# Name of small company gifts (as marketing tool)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What's the name of those small things that companies give away to visitors as gifts when participating at some exposition. Like hats, pens, dvds, usb drives, mouse pads, and so on ?

We say "gadgets", but perhaps in English they use another word (I see in the dictionary that gadget seems to refer to electronic stuff, while here they can be hat with a logo, mouse pads or whatever) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Promotional products* is the formal term.

*Swag* (used collectively) is currently the cool term among event planners. Pros sometimes explain it ironically (to clients who have no sense of either humor or the language) as “Souvenirs, Wearables And Gifts” or “Stuff We All Get”

*Tchotchkes* (a Yiddish term) has been around for a long time.

*Handouts*, *giveaways*, *trinkets*, *doodads*, *goodies* and of course *gifts* are also used.

Comment: @Mina You're very welcome. However, you need not rush to accept this answer; it is quite possible that something better will come along.

Comment: +1 for _swag_. Reminds me of a band name my daughter came up with: _Swag with No Pockets_.

Comment: Another +1 for swag specifically

Comment: Don't forget *freebies*.  And I've also seen *Promotional Items* (instead of *products*)

Comment: Nice answer; +1! I hear *swag* a lot. In my family we tend to just call it "free stuff" ;)

Comment: @Jim Yes, indeed. Also *ballast* and *promo-trash*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word [premium](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/premium?s=t) is best used here, especially the first two definitions:

> 1. a prize, bonus, or award given as an inducement, as to purchase products, enter competitions initiated by business interests, etc.
> 2. a bonus, gift, or sum additional to price, wages, interest, or the like.

Comment: For a long time in the past at trade shows & etc. the traditional name was "premiums" for companies planning to provide business reminder items for the attendees to take home. It never applied very well from the recipients' point of view, but the slang term "swag" cheapens the often considerable investment the co.s spend to provide the customized items. E.G. - Attendees asking "How much stuff did you get in your swag bag?"